# Write a program to break long input lines into two or more shorter lines of length at most n

Tags: c

I am currently learning C and working on a problem that breaks input lines into lengths of n. Below is my current code where n is set to 30. When it reaches the n-th index it replaces that index with ' ' and then line breaks, but it will only do it for the first n characters and I'm unsure what isn't getting rest in order to it to continue making a new line at the nth index.

```
int getline2(void);

int c, len, cut, counter;
char line[MAXLINE];

main() {

    while ((len = getline2()) > 0) {
        if (len > BREAK) {
            c = 0;
            counter = 0;

            while (c < len) {
                if (line[c] == ' ') {
                    counter = c;
                }

                if (counter == BREAK) {
                    line[counter] = '\n';
                    counter = 0;
                }
                counter++;
                c++;
            }
        }
        printf("%s", line);
    }

    return 0;
}

int getline2(void) {
    int c, i;
    extern char line[];

    for (i = 0; i < MAXLINE - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
        line[i] = c; //i gets incremented at the end of the loop
    if (c == '\n') {
        line[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    line[i] = '\0';

    return i;
}
```

Comment: You're doing this the hard way.  Just use `char line[BREAK + 1];` then read using `fgets()`.  If the line doesn't end with `\n`, you just read part of a longer line and you've broken it already.

Comment: Please format your code in a readable manner using proper indentation.

Comment: What do you mean, break a line? At a space? It's possible to find the [least weight subsequence](https://xxyxyz.org/line-breaking/).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little too complicated:

- you do not need to store the bytes read from the file into an array, just output them one at a time, keeping track of the line length
- when the line would become too long, output a newline and reset the count before you output the byte.
- also not that none of these global variables deserves to be global.
- and the prototype for `main` should be either `int main()`, `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) or equivalent.` main()` is an obsolete syntax that should be avoided.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BREAK 30

int main() {
    int c;
    int len = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            putchar(c);
            len = 0;
        } else {
            if (len >= BREAK) {
                putchar('\n');
                len = 0;
            }
            putchar(c);
            len++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```